# view doesn't come back after video plays

Tags: ios

I'm running the following code. The video plays fine but after it finishes it just goes to a black srcreen, my original view never comes back. When I tap on the black screen i just see the message "loading....." Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

```
- (IBAction)video:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                             pathForResource:@"IMG_0973" ofType:@"MOV"]];
        moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDonePressed:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:moviePlayer];



        moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
        //moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=NO;
        [moviePlayer play];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

    }

}

- (void) moviePlayBackDonePressed:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [moviePlayer stop];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:moviePlayer];


    if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    moviePlayer=nil;
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [moviePlayer stop];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

    if ([moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tap on the movie to bring up the *Done* button?

Answer (score 1):

Add this notification Method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePreloadDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
                                               object:player];
```

This method is called after your movie is loaded and in this method you add your moviePlayer view.

```
-(void)moviePreloadDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{

   moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
   [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
   [moviePlayer play];
   [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your video IBAction, you need to add the subview before you tell it to play.  Switch the lines [moviePlayer play] and [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view]. Let us know it it works!  Actually you may need to place moviePlayer play even after the full screen line.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  You are using NSNotification.  When I played my movie in my app, I used the same code, but without the NSNotification, and the video played, and the Done button dismissed my video and brought back my original view.  Still, let us know how it goes.

Comment: the done button works fine. It's when the movie finishes running that it goes to black and stays there.  When I tap the screen it displays "running"  I switched the lines per your suggestion - but no change.

Comment: Here is what I did to get a video playing without MPMoviePlayer.  I created a cell for my table view with a UIWebview in it.  Then...    VideoCell *videoCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"VideoCell"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[_theBigArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[videoCell.webView loadRequest:request];
cell = videoCell;         _theBigArray holds the link to the video I want to show.  This makes a small video preview with a play button.  Push the play button and the video plays in full screen.

Comment: The done button shows, and when I push that, it brings me back to my original tableview.  This works great for the videos I am showing which are all on YouTube.  Hope maybe this helps!! @vboombatz

Answer (score 0):

```
i think this will help you .....


 -(void)playVideo
{

    NSString *contentURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xyz" ofType:@"mp4"];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:contentURL]];

    if (moviePlayerViewController)
    {
        [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

        [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MovieFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer];

        [moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];

        [navi presentModalViewController:moviePlayerViewController animated:NO];

        [moviePlayerViewController release];

        moviePlayerViewController  = nil;
    }

}
-(void)MovieFinished:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = (MPMoviePlayerController *)notification.object;

   [player stop];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

//do rest of the stuff


}
```

Comment: where does 'navi' come from? Thanks.

Comment: it's uinavigationcontroller's object , to push the viewcontroller to moviePlayerViewController to play the video , or you can use presentModalViewController